# Re-stun monsters at Betrayal at HotH

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In Betrayal at House on the Hill, you can stun monsters by attacking them, however: they do not die. The rules say a stunned monster can be attacked again.

Is a monster stunned again when attacked while it’s stunned, meaning you can stun a monster again on your next turn so it will miss its turn repeatedly?

What about two heros stun a monster in the same round, does the stun stack meaning the monster misses multiple rounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this bgg thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/826270/stunned-monsters) it is explained that a monster can not be stunned twice. If the player attacking the monster has a special weapon (based on the haunt) it can damage the monster. But if your attack only stuns, stunning a stunned character does not stun it anymore.